# google storage bucket upload permissions

Tags: acl, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have tried to create "vendor dropbox" , using the instructions  in [Google cloud storage documntation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration)
the folloing set of commands were executed :

creating the bucket

```
gsutil  mb gs://customer-10
```

adding external user permissions

```
gsutil chacl  -u user@company.com:FC gs://customer-10
```

adding default acl

```
gsutil chdefacl  -u -u user@company.com:FC gs://customer-10
```

verify the acl modifications , using the command 
`gsutil getacl gs://customer-10`   (verified succesfuly )

```
     <Entry>
    <Scope type="UserByEmail">
        <EmailAddress>user@company.com</EmailAddress>
        <Name>firstname lastname</Name>
    </Scope>
    <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
</Entry>
```

but when the user is accessing the bucket , using the link 
https://storage.cloud.google.com/?arg=customer-10&pli=1#customer-10

it is **not** possible to upload any file into this bucket .

What is missing in my scenario ?  please help

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved in gsutil version 3.37. 
Currently it is working as documented .